# How do I get nuxtServerInit to dispatch an action on the Server?

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have a nuxt project using firebase.  I want to use SSR and initiate and populate the store on SSR but I cannot get the code below to work.

I am working on a nuxt project I have a plugin/firebase project that initiates the firebase sdk.  I have an asyncData function that works.

in my /store/index.js file I export the state function and the actions.  In the actions I have the async nuxtServerInit that dispatches a `posts/getPosts' action passing the context.

In my `store/index` I have

```
export const state = () => ({})

export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit({ dispatch }, context) {
    await dispatch('posts/getPosts', context)
  }
}
```

In my 'store/posts.js` I have

```
import { db } from '~/plugins/firebase'

export const state = () => ({
  ActivePosts: []
})

export const actions = {
  getPosts({ commit }) {
    const postList = []
    return db
      .collection('posts')
      .where('status', '==', 'approved')
      .orderBy('CreatedAt', 'desc')
      .get()
      .then(docs => {
        docs.forEach(doc => {
          const newPost = doc.data()
          newPost.id = doc.id
          this.postList.push(newPost)
          console.log(newPost)
        })
      })
      .then(() => {
        commit('addPosts', postList)
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e))
  }
}
```

In my firebase plugin I have

```
import firebase from 'firebase'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: '<<correctkey>>.',
  authDomain: '<<correctkey>>',
  databaseURL: '<<correctUrl>>',
  projectId: '<<correctid>>',
  storageBucket: '<<correctbucket>>',
  messagingSenderId: '<<correctkey>>',
  appId: '<<correctkey>>'
}

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
}

export const db = firebase.firestore()
export const auth = firebase.auth()
```

This code, at least I thought, should initiate my store on the server and fill it with post values.  When I check my store in vue developer tools there are no values in the store, although the getter is present and the state values(empty array) is present.  This tells me that the store is initiated and the module is present, at least on the client side.

Comment: Does your `console.log(newPost)` show anything? I don't think you need the 'this' on postList when you push to it. And the `commit('addPosts', postList)` doesn't need its own '.then', you can just put it after your for loop.

Comment: I don’t get any log in the terminal. Which is why I didn’t think it was running at all on the server

Comment: Are you sure doc.data(), as a function is right? Console.log(doc) and see what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was not with my action but the mutation. Here is the final code that got me to working.

```
import { db } from '~/plugins/firebase'

export const state = () => ({
  ActivePosts: []
})

export const getters = {
  getPosts(state) {
    return state.ActivePosts
  }
}

export const mutations = {
  addPosts(state, payload) { // had to change { state } to state.
    state.ActivePosts.push(payload)
  }
}

export const actions = {
  getPosts({ commit }) {
    const postList = []
    return db
      .collection('posts')
      .where('status', '==', 'approved')
      .orderBy('CreatedAt', 'desc')
      .get()
      .then(docs => {
        docs.forEach(doc => {
          const newPost = doc.data()
          newPost.id = doc.id
          postList.push(newPost) //removed the `this.`
        })
          commit('addPosts', postList) //moved the commit to the  // moved the commit out of its own then.
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e))
  }
}
```